# I am begginer in Djangio forgive me if it is stupid question. What actually do order_by() in Django?

Tags: python, django

I read documentation they are saying order_by() return a new QuerySet. but When I print Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date') where Question is class name in models.py it print queryset object. I am confused that is order_by() actually return a new Queryset or actually execute a query ?
please explain what is happening internally during execution in Django in below code?

```
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from .models import Question
  def index(request): 
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
   output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
   return HttpResponse(output)
```

and also please explain line 5 in above code?

Comment: You order the questions by the date these got published with the most recent question first.

Comment: It does both, an implicit `all` since you don't include any other query

Comment: But what about line 5 in code. Can you explain in details?

Answer (score 0):

Django queries are lazily executed so it doesn't perform the query until you attempt to get the results, hence why it says it returns a query set. You attempt to get the results when you iterate over them for the list comprehension in line 5..

Line 5 is just a list comprehension used within a joining string operation

Comment: So tell me when query will execute ?

Comment: line 5 when you reference the `latest_question_list`

Comment: It means order_by return only a query and does not execute a query.

Comment: but when i print a latest_question_list before line 5 it also show me results about table.

Comment: It means query will not execute untill we use latest_question_list. is it true?

Comment: @Sanwarlal - Thats correct, querysets are not executed until you need to use their values for something